# Excel vba invalid qualifier error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying the following  vba code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Workbooks("Contractor Manpower Tracking_NE_02.06.2015.xlsx").Activate

    arr = Sheets("NE_Scheme").Range("I3:I89").Value
    Workbooks("Scheme.xltm").Activate
    For i = 1 To arr.Length
       Cells(i, 4) = arr(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

I am getting the compile error: `invalid qualifier`.

Comment: It's hard to test without having some information to work with but I think you should just have arr = Sheets("NE_Scheme").Range("I3:I89") instead of the .value

Comment: Its still not working even if i delete the .value part

Comment: Does it give the same error or a new one?

Comment: Declare `Arr` without the parentheses and use `Len(Arr)`. There is no `Length` property in VBA, although there is for strings in .Net, I think.

Comment: when changed to Len(arr) error coming variable required cant assign to expression

Comment: I assume you actually want `ubound`, as others have suggested, which gives the number of elements (more or less) in the array.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim arr() As Variant
  Dim i As Integer

  Dim wb as WorkBook
  Dim str as String
  set wb=Workbooks("Contractor Manpower Tracking_NE_02.06.2015.xlsx")
  If wb is nothing then
  MsgBox "Workbook Contractor Manpower Tracking_NE_02.06.2015.xlsx not found"
  Else
   Dim abc

   For Each abc In wb.Sheets
   If abc.Name="NE_Scheme" then
    str=abc.Name
    Exit For
   End If
   Next
  If str="" then 
   MsgBox "No sheet called NE_Scheme in the current workbook"
   Exit Sub
  Else
   arr = wb.Sheets("NE_Scheme").Range("I3:I89").Value
  End If
  End If

  Workbooks("Scheme.xltm").Activate
  'Need sheet name here to write
  For i = 1 To Ubound(arr)
       Cells(i, 4) = arr(i,1)
       Next i


  End Sub
```

Added arr(i,1), since you can access the value of the variant only like arr(i,1)
and added Ubound instead of Length

Comment: Can you tell me on which line? Is it while assigning the the variant value to the Cells `Cells(i, 4) = arr(i,1)`  ?

Comment: After the line `Workbooks("Scheme.xltm").Activate` can u add the sheet on which you are performing the operation?

Comment: It is giving runtime error '9' but not highlighting the line as to where the error is occuring meanwhile it is activating only the first workbook

Comment: Edited the code, now it will give you where the error is, also you need the sheet name for the workbook **Scheme.xltm** where you are writing the variant value.

Comment: That means your first work book either doesn't have the sheet NE_Scheme or else the case of the characters would be different. Can you please check?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Workbooks("Book2.xlsx").Activate

    arr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I3:I89").Value
    Workbooks("Book1.xltm").Activate
    For Row = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For Col = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 4) = arr(Row, Col)
        Next Col
    Next Row

End Sub
```

Comment: I know this is a rarity but at sometimes the name you saved it as is not what Excel sees it as. When you run the macro and it fails, hit debug and in the top left, look at the two file names next to VBAProject(FILENAME).

Comment: Actually i have two files with NE_Scheme and Sheet2 of same workbook

Comment: Can you show me what you see there? I think that could be your issue.

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more details on what's not working, testing that code out on 2 workbooks with the given names and having values in I3 -> I89 in book2, it takes the values and starts placing them in book1, sheet1 D1 -> D87

Comment: upto arr the code is working fine after that itt is not working properly

Comment: Thanks I got it but if we want to incorporate two arrays than how ro change the upper bound of the array